# Estimate average of a dataset when thresholded

Tags: dataset, mean, threshold

Suppose I have a dataset $x_i$ (with $x_i >= 0$) of N samples. I would like to determine the average of the data when the data is limited to some theshold c:

$limitedaverage(x,c) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N max(x_i,c)$

Problem is I don't have access to the actual samples, I only know some aggregate statistics of the data: the sum, sum of squares, etc, up to a certain order k:

$\sum x$, $\sum x^2$, $\sum x^3$ ... $\sum x^k$

I'm looking for a way to estimate the above limited average for a given c and given said aggregates.

Intuitively I've been able to get a rough idea for k=2: given $\sum x$ and $\sum x^2$ one can calculate the average and the standard deviation and this tells me whether there are any samples that are significantly below c and would become clipped. But also given $\sum x^3$ and $\sum x^4$ I'm sure it's possible to get a more accurate estimate.

My idea is that it should be possible to exploit $max(x,c) = \lim_{k \to \infty} (x^k+c^k)^\frac{1}{k}$ but from here I'm stuck.

Any hints?

Comment: This [discussion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3525/when-are-probability-distributions-completely-determined-by-their-moments) gives good information about estimating distributions from their moments.  See [Truncated distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) for the expected value given the distribution and threshold $c$.  So, maybe estimate the distribution using the sample moments, then calculate the truncated mean.  Open questions right now are consistency, bias, variance, and limiting distribution, among others.  Maybe study the performance using simulation?